# What is the opposite of "cryptography"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Cryptography is about writing something that is hard/impossible to read without the correct key, basically, it is about hiding.

Now, what do you call:

- Writing in a way **that is easy to understand**, even without a cultural background/context information?

For example, I could Write "Apple" but for someone who does not speak English, "Apple" has no meaning instead, if we draw an apple, almost everyone will understand.

**Sample sentences:**

> 1. When teaching reading to children we need some book that is _____.
> 2. Contrary to cryptography, ________ is about showing information in the most understandable way.
> 3. Thanks to ________, we can teach rudimentary of maths even to someone that is not able to read/write.

Comment: Well, there is the adjective "clear" and the noun "clarity".

Comment: maybe a more specific word referring exactly to "writing" ?

Comment: This isn't the opposite of a cryptographer, the opposite of a cryptographer, would be someone that deciphers encrypted messages.

Comment: @Gary The opposite of the cryptographer is the cryptoanalyst in most contexts. Though it's clearly not what this question is about.

Comment: The opposite of encrypted text is plaintext: _In cryptography, plaintext, or cleartext, is un-encrypted information, as opposed to information encrypted for storage or transmission._ (Wikipedia article on Plaintext)

Comment: Your basic assumption is a bit flawed. **Encryption** is "converting some medium into something that is hard/impossible to read without they correct key", the opposite of which is decryption. Cryptography is the subject which deals with both, encryption and decryption.

Comment: well, anyway the sample senteces covers enough what I mean

Comment: I think the OP perhaps means to say "What is the opposite of **cryptic**" rather than cryptography. They share a root but have different meanings.

Comment: While it isn't the opposite, what you are looking for is for something to written ***Intuitively***. While instructions can be made ***intuitive*** to a native speaker I am unsure if there is a way to make text ***intuitive*** to someone unfamiliar with the language.

Answer (score 2):

This would be someone adept at writing in **plain** English.

Plain is a recognised term to describe the use of the English language in the way you have described.

See:

[***Plain English Campaign***](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk)

> Since 1979, we have been campaigning against gobbledygook, jargon and
>   misleading public information. We have helped many government
>   departments and other official organisations with their documents,
>   reports and publications. We believe that everyone should have access
>   to clear and concise information

.

Answer (score 1):

**A short backdrop on Cryptography**

Using cryptography, we `encrypt` something or make something impossible to be read by the unintended reader (as he does not have the key). It's more like locking the information inside a box, which can only be opened by someone possessing the key. So we do not make something difficult to read, we make it inaccessible to any unintended audience. The opposite of this process is to `decrypt` the information by opening the locked box using the key.

However, by the explanation which you provided, I think that you need the word for **something which is easily understood**.

Words like **lucid**, **articulate**, **intelligible** etc convey that meaning. Please note that the opposite of lucid would not be encrypted, but abstruse, obscure, muddled, puzzling and so on.

You may like to check out these thesaurus links:

[Lucid](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lucid)

[Easily understood](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/easily%20understood)

Comment: It's a generally good answer, but night is most certainly the opposite of day, just as decryption is the opposite of encryption.